# How to pull out include a div from cross domain page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cross-domain

I want to include a calculator on my own personal website that is found on another domain found at...

http://www.r-control.com/library/sip-energy-savings-calculator/

I actually just want the calculator div on my page, not all the navbars and sidebars.

It this possible to do with an iframe or jquery?

Or is it possible to include the entire page on my website, but just "hide" the parts that I don't wanna see?

Please advise.

Thanks

Comment: Not possible... develop your own calculator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it would be better, if you learn elements in that page, and rewrite it.

Of cource you can parce result of the query(even if that server allows cross domain request), and show only needed form with needed styles. But for result you need to send this form to server(this request might not be support cross domain), and then parce results as well.

I think easiest way is to apply reverse engineering to make the similar result.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the fact that  you'd literally just ripping the content from another website (I don't think the original authors would like that), this is not possible, like [Muthu Kumaran already mentioned in his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45932240/how-to-pull-out-include-a-div-from-cross-domain-page/45932498#comment78822545_45932240).

I highly encourage you to develop your own calculator!

Comment: Actually R-Control is my supplier, so not really ripping them off.  I was planning on leaving certain elements.  I just don't want the navbar and sidebar and footer.  If this was going to be easy, I wanted to do it.  But if not, I won't even bother.  I'll just put a link to their page instead.  -Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As I can see this website does not provide calculator widget code to integrate somewhere else. So first you need to find out is there any other website similar to this which gives widget code.

If you still want to integrate the same calculator you will need to try some css hacks after integrating the same using iframe as follows -

```
#masthead {
    display: none !important;
}

.sixteen.columns > img {
    display: none !important;
}

#page .container #secondary {
    display: none !important;
}

.site-footer {
    display: none !important;
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply.  I initially thought to do what you suggested, but I don't think CSS will "drill down" into a cross domain.  Doesn't seem to work for me anyway.